# Customize sharepoint menu

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have this requirement to display site sub menu items in horizonatl direction instead of vertical.

```
 Home | Site1 | Site2
        Page1 | Page2 | Page3
```

Is there any attribute avaliable in Sharepoint:ASPMenu to achieve this. We dont intend to write code behind for this. Any suggestions on how to achieve this thru Sharepoint desinger.

Answer (score 0):

is the Orientation property available?

where "Orientation" is Orientation.Horizontal

see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ka1z07s